# Multiple values in userform listbox - what's wrong with my code

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, multiple-value, vba

I don't know how to program in this language so I have to rely on Google. Taken bits from here and there and I suspect that I have two puzzles that don't fit at the moment. I am getting `runtime error 9 subscript out of range` because of this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("c2").End(xlDown).Select = myVar
```

Here's my code:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Skráningar")

'Taeki gögn í gagnagrunn
myVar = ""

For X = 0 To Me.taeki.ListCount - 1
    If Me.taeki.Selected(X) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & "," & Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next X

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("c2").End(xlDown).Select = myVar

'find first empty row in database
'iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
 iRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.timutbox.Value) = "" Then
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Vinsamlega skráðu hversu lengi tækið var í notkun"
Exit Sub
End If


Me.Hide

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.dagsbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.timutbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.sandbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.vedurbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.bilunbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.athbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.taeki.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.svaedi.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
'clear the data
Me.dagsbox.Value = ""
Me.timutbox.Value = ""
Me.sandbox.Value = ""
Me.vedurbox.Value = ""
Me.bilunbox.Value = ""
Me.athbox.Value = ""
Me.taeki.Value = ""
Me.svaedi.Value = ""
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
```

Comment: Hello Unnar. In the line you indicated, you are trying to select a cell and then equate it to a value. Instead try this `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C2").End(xlDown).value = myVar`  But ensure that `Sheet4` exists.

Comment: With this line:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skráningar").Range("C2").Value = myVar

I'm able to get the value from the listbox but I need it to look the next empty cell in a row for the next entry. What can I do about that problem?

Comment: And thanks a lot for the help Calico! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No Problem. The following statement in you code finds the next blank row in Column A. `iRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`. The data from your form is then outputted to this row it seems. Does it currently not do that? Please elaborate on what is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: It does that for all the other entries in the userform. The value from the listbox, only goes to this one cell (C2)

Comment: Please try code in answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Skráningar")

'Taeki gögn í gagnagrunn
myVar = ""

For X = 0 To Me.taeki.ListCount - 1
    If Me.taeki.Selected(X) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & "," & Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next X

'find first empty row in database
'iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
 iRow = ws.range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 ws.Range("C" & iRow).value = myVar

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.timutbox.Value) = "" Then
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Vinsamlega skráðu hversu lengi tækið var í notkun"
Exit Sub
End If


Me.Hide

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.dagsbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.timutbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.sandbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.vedurbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.bilunbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.athbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.taeki.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.svaedi.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
'clear the data
Me.dagsbox.Value = ""
Me.timutbox.Value = ""
Me.sandbox.Value = ""
Me.vedurbox.Value = ""
Me.bilunbox.Value = ""
Me.athbox.Value = ""
Me.taeki.Value = ""
Me.svaedi.Value = ""
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
```

EDIT:
I have changed how `iRow` is calculated, and removed reference to sheet4

Does that do what you need?

Comment: just noticed you have 2 sheets `Sheet4` and `Skráningar` should the Userform output and the value of `myvar` be on the same sheet on the next blank line? If so.. change this line to the following:    `ws.Range("C" & iRow).value = myVar`

Comment: Still trying to figure this out. Working with what you've been helping me with. I don't have two sheets, Skráningar is the name of sheet4

Comment: Hi oh ok. Probably worth only using one reference in the VBA code for clarity. Can you explain what is going wrong with the code i posted above? I dont have the time to recreate the sheet/userforms to test myself.

Comment: iRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skráningar").Range("C" & iRow).Value = myVar

With these two lines, I can enter data without a troublecode but now the data from the listbox is not appearing

Comment: I have edited the code above. Namely the following two lines `     iRow = ws.range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`  and `ws.Range("C" & iRow).value = myVar`. Make sure the `Me.timutbox` has an entry otherwise the data from the listbox will not be printed (this is how the code is setup). Please try again and let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks again for all the help Calico. I tried the code you edited, managed to enter the data without a trouble code but didn't get the listbox entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Skráningar")

'Taeki gögn í gagnagrunn
myVar = ""

For X = 0 To Me.taeki.ListCount - 1
    If Me.taeki.Selected(X) Then
        If myVar = "" Then
            myVar = Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        Else
            myVar = myVar & "," & Me.taeki.List(X, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next X

'find first empty row in database
'iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _ SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
 iRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 ws.Range("C" & iRow).Value = myVar

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.timutbox.Value) = "" Then
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Vinsamlega skráðu hversu lengi tækið var í notkun"
Exit Sub
End If


Me.Hide

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.dagsbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.timutbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.sandbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.vedurbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.bilunbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.athbox.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.taeki.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.svaedi.Value


MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Added"
'clear the data
Me.dagsbox.Value = ""
Me.timutbox.Value = ""
Me.sandbox.Value = ""
Me.vedurbox.Value = ""
Me.bilunbox.Value = ""
Me.athbox.Value = ""
Me.taeki.Value = ""
Me.svaedi.Value = ""
Me.dagsbox.SetFocus
```

This is the current code.